# Is there a way to move each Nth row of a text file into a specific column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, readr

Here is what my text file data looks like:

1 Abigail Seltzer

6019 8th St NW

Washington, DC-20011

Not Employed Not Employed

6019 8th St. NW

Washington,DC-20011

Credit Card 03/11/2022 $10,000.00 $10,00.00

2 Danita Cole

416 Shepherd St NW

Washington, DC-20005

Not Employed Not Employed

416 Shepherd Street NW

Washington,DC-20011

Credit Card 03/11/2022 $100.00 $350.00

3 Landon James

612 Quintana Pl NW

Washington, DC-20011

Social Inclusion Manager Brookfield Properties

655 New York Ave NW

Washington,DC-20000

Credit Card 03/11/2022 $100.00 $100.00

To be clear, each time there is a number before the name (1 Abigail, 2 Danita) the next 6 rows follow without blank rows, then there is one blank row after the 7th row before the next numbered entry (between 'Credit Card 03/11/2022 $10,000.00 $10,00.00' and '2 Danita')). So there are no blank rows between '1 Abigail Seltzer' and '6019 8th St NW'.

I would like to put each of the grouped rows into their own 7 columns - for each grouping of 7 grows, so:

column1
1 Abigail Seltzer
2 Danita Cole
3 Landon James

column2
6019 8th St NW
416 Shepherd St NW
612 Quintana Pl NW

column 3
Washington, DC-20011
Washington, DC-20005
Washington, DC-20000

And so on.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean put them in their own column? Do you want the output to be a data frame, or do you want to rearrange the lines and save them to a new text file?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the text file using `readLines`, and convert the resulting vector into a matrix with 8 rows. When you transpose this matrix, all your fields will have their own column

```r
t(matrix(readLines("../mytext.txt"), nrow = 8))
#>      [,1]                [,2]                 [,3]                  
#> [1,] "1 Abigail Seltzer" "6019 8th St NW"     "Washington, DC-20011"
#> [2,] "2 Danita Cole"     "416 Shepherd St NW" "Washington, DC-20005"
#> [3,] "3 Landon James"    "612 Quintana Pl NW" "Washington, DC-20011"
#>      [,4]                                            
#> [1,] "Not Employed Not Employed"                     
#> [2,] "Not Employed Not Employed"                     
#> [3,] "Social Inclusion Manager Brookfield Properties"
#>      [,5]                     [,6]                 
#> [1,] "6019 8th St. NW"        "Washington,DC-20011"
#> [2,] "416 Shepherd Street NW" "Washington,DC-20011"
#> [3,] "655 New York Ave NW"    "Washington,DC-20000"
#>      [,7]                                     [,8]
#> [1,] "Credit Card 03/11/2022 $100.00 $100.00" ""  
#> [2,] "Credit Card 03/11/2022 $100.00 $350.00" ""  
#> [3,] "Credit Card 03/11/2022 $100.00 $100.00" ""
```

You could convert this into a data frame with `as.data.frame` if you wished.

Comment: Thanks! Greatly appreciated!